# Laravel, Call function from class returns null value

Tags: php, laravel

How to get values from the function below if I want to put it in a class? acutally if I called it directly from controller it works fine but when I called it from class it returns null value please help me
Simply I need to add this in the screen function in a class so no need to repeat the code inside the controller many times, please note that in the controller function it works fine but in class it returns null value
[image]

Class:

```
public function getStoresDistance($allstores)
{
    $stores = collect([]);
    foreach (session('storeinfo') as $storeInfo) {
        $store = $allstores->find($storeInfo['id']);
        if ($store) {
            $store->distance = $storeInfo['distance'];
            $stores[] = $store;
            if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
                Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
                    $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
                    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);

                    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                        $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
                        $this->count(),
                        $perPage,
                        $page,
                        $options
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call from controller:

```
$allstores = Storeinfo::where('show', 'y')->get();
$findstores = Helper::getStoresDistance($allstores);
```

Comment: 3rd line of this method already have a return statement, so the code below won't be executed. Is this what you want?

Comment: Even without that first return (which makes 95% of the code in that function moot), there are several situations when it would return null (or more accurately, not return anything.. aka void). Ex: `session('storeinfo')` is an empty array, if `$store` is empty and if `Collection::hasMacro('paginate')` is truthy.

Comment: please share this helper locate and share class which called this helper

Comment: I also don't see the point of saving the stores in `$stores`? You only push elements to it but you never use it for anything?

Comment: @LevFlavien sorry for this mistake I added this because I was test the fubction

Answer (score 0):

You need 'return' on function that you want to call (return what data to send/call)

just type 'Class::function' inside your class
like this

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{

public function yourController()
{
    $allstores = Storeinfo::where('show', 'y')->get();
    $findstores = ExampleController::getStoresDistance($allstores);
    return $findstores;
}

public function getStoresDistance($allstores)
{
    $stores = collect([]);

    return session('storeinfo');
    foreach (session('storeinfo') as $storeInfo) {
        $store = $allstores->find($storeInfo['id']);
        if ($store) {
            $store->distance = $storeInfo['distance'];
            $stores[] = $store;
            if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
                Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
                    $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
                    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);

                    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                        $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
                        $this->count(),
                        $perPage,
                        $page,
                        $options
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is common for multiple controllers, move it to a PHP trait. Traits are specifically designed for reusability purpose. You can then use that trait in your controller and call its function as you would your controller functions like so `$this->yourFunction()`. Below is how your code will look:

**Trait:**

```
trait StoresDistance
{
    public function storesDistance(){}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    use StoresDistance;

    public function getStoresDistance($allstores)
    {
         // some code
         $this->storesDistance();
         // some code
    }
}
```

Reference Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php